# Scanning a Database and sending an e-mail of changes of a certain tag

Tags: database, email, database-scan

I have a Database with some goods.These goods have a price on this database. I would like somehow scan this database and when a price of a product changes I want to send an e-mail to a specific address.Is this possible?What programming language should I use php? And What can i do so as to manage this problem? I am kind new to databses and a help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either cache all the prices and run a script that selects all and compares them, or you can set up a trigger on UPDATE that will call a user defined function or stored procedure. From there, you can choose what/where to email.